# Access value within options of a form

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have a JQuery Python that I don't know how to solve... 
I tried many things but nothing work.

I have a form using a dropdown button with many options listing the users linked to a specific team. As option value I put the user ID and then his first and last-name

```
<form>
    <select id="pick-chart" class="form-control pick-chart">
         <option value="0">Compare with</option>
          {% for i in team_list_pop %}
          <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.first_name}} {{i.last_name}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
     </select>
</form>
```

Using JQuery I would like to be able to access the user first name (i.first_name) in order to use it as a header in another div.

```
 $(".pick-chart").change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val != 0) {
                    info_process.data.datasets[1].data = info_array[val];
                    info_process.update();
                    var name = $("option").find('option').text();
                    $("#ops-info").empty()
                    $("#dif-info").empty()
                    $("#info-head").empty()
                    ops = opposed_model[val]
                    dif = differ_model[val]
                    $("#info-head").append(" with" + " " + name );
                    for(var x = 0; x < ops.length; x++){
                      if (ops[x] <= 6){
                        $("#ops-info").append("<div>"+ops[x]+"</div>");
                        }
                    }
                    for(var x = 0; x < dif.length; x++){
                      if (dif[x] <= 6){
                        $("#diff-info").append("<div>"+dif[x]+"</div>");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
            info_process.data.datasets[1].data = [];
            document.getElementById("ops-info").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("diff-info").innerHTML = "";

        }
        info_process.update();
    });
```

I tried using :

```
var name = $("option").find('option').text();
```

when actualy I would need to have option id="x" where x is stored as val ..

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(this).find(':selected').text()
```

```js
$("select").change(function(event){
  console.log($(this).find(':selected').text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="select">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
</select>
</form>
<h1 id="header"></h1>
```